# Replace different combinations of whitespaces, tabs and carriage returns with a single white space

Tags: java, apache-stringutils

I would likwe to replace different combinations of whitespaces, tabs and carriage returns with a single white space.

So far i got a solution that works:

```
String stringValue="";
stringValue = stringValue.replaceAll(";", ",");
stringValue = stringValue.replaceAll("\\\\n+", " ");
stringValue = stringValue.replaceAll("\\\\r+", " ");
stringValue = stringValue.replaceAll("\\\\t+", " ");
stringValue = stringValue.replaceAll(" +", " ");
```

Input: test\n\t\r123 ;123
Output:test123,123

is there a prettier solution to this ?

Comment: `stringValue = stringValue.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");`

Comment: @jsheeran I think you can make an answer with this.

Comment: @OP You say your existing solution works, but I'm slightly confused as to why you're using `"\\\\n+"` etc. Are you looking to match newline characters, or a literal backslash followed by one or more `n`s?

Comment: I'm getting the data from an xml file and i'm writing it to csv via CsvWriter.write (javacsv-2.0.jar). Through debugging i found the above solution. "\\s+" doesn't help for some reason.

Comment: In that case, maybe something like `"\\\\[nrt]+| +"`? Do you have some sample data?

Comment: @jsheeran: That's what i was looking for. Thanks

Comment: PS: this site https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html (and its siblings) is a fantastic resource when tuning regexp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\s` class matches whitespace characters. Thus:

```
stringValue = stringValue.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

To substitute whitespace escape strings per the question, the four regexes can be combined as follows:

```
"(?:\\\\[nrt])+| +"
```